# Install mysql package using puppet so it will be updated automatically

Tags: mysql, puppet

I want to install the MySQL package onto servers using Puppet. The package should be updated after a new release of the package. How can I write a manifest for that?

Answer (score 2):

Using `ensure => latest` tells Puppet to update the package to the latest version. For example,

```
package { "mysql-server": 
  ensure => latest
}
```

This assumes that your server updates its package cache on a regular basis and that the server's Puppet client runs on a regular basis (most do). From the [Puppet Labs documentation](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/type.html#package-attribute-ensure):

> On packaging systems that can retrieve new packages on their own, you
>   can choose which package to retrieve by specifying a version number or
>   `latest` as the ensure value.

Comment: Though it may seem obvious, this also assumes that the server runs Puppet on a regular schedule.  The automatic updates are managed by Puppet on a continuing basis; they are not somehow rolled in to the installed package itself, as the OP could be read to be requesting.

Comment: That is a useful clarification @JohnBollinger. I have updated my answer to reflect your comment.